# Can P vs NP be written as a statement in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

For the problem of $P\neq NP$ it would be useful to have a precise mathematical statement **of the question** in some logic like set theory or some generalisation of it. And then we could ask given the axioms of this logic is the statement true of false.

So far I've only seen statements that use English words like, "runs for n steps" and so on.

Is there a precise statement in some logic that can encode even the question of $N\neq NP$? (Or is that part of the problem?)

Comment: Yes it could be, especially considering regarding the equality of two sets. You find often times though mathematicians do not have a desire to break down every statement into the most rigorous logical symbols in order to start or complete a proof, there is very little advantage in doing so here.

Comment: "it would be useful to have a precise mathematical statement of the question in some logic like set theory or some generalisation of it." Why? Set theory is a bit like machine code - it's just not very convenient for actually writing mathematics in. P vs. NP is perfectly precise, and translating it into set theory is routine but incredibly tedious; what would be gained by doing so?

Comment: Exactly, nothing would be gained. Mathematical proof is mostly a social process, mathematicians do not translate their arguments into purely logical statements and symbols, they generally just go ask a colleague if they are equally convinced or they try to get published or something like this. There is nothing to be gained.

Comment: See [$\mathsf P \text { versus } \mathsf {NP}$ : formal defintiion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem#P_and_NP) : it is quite formal.

Comment: Of course something would be gained. If the question could only be stated in a vague way then it is not a proper question. @Maruo that is not my understanding of "formal". That is using English words and grammar. Also if you knew which set of axioms you need to define the question this would frame the question better.